# jQuery trigger on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make jQuery run when my webpage has finished loading?

This is not what I want. All that this does is wait for the page to finish loading before any Javascript CAN be run.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Code here
});
```

What I want is for this to run when the page loads. I don't want it to wait for `'click'` or `'change'`. Can I add a `'load'` or something to this?

```
$(document).on("change", "#input", function(e) {
   $("#output").val($(this).val());
});
```

A workaround I have been using is to use jQuery to "change" the selected option on a select box, thereby triggering the code I actually want to run.

---

I have seen a bunch of questions like this, but every time the answer just says to use `$(document).ready(function(){//Code});` which is not what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

---

---

**EDIT:** Here is a better example of what I'm looking for.

This code below will run when the element with the id of 'input' is clicked. That is the only time it will run. I would like for it to run as soon as it is ready - as soon as `$(document).ready(function(){});` can run it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("change", "#input", function(e) {
       $("#output").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

I think that this would work, but I was hoping for a nicer solution and one that doesn't require me to rewrite everything as functions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function runWhenReady(){
       $("#output").val($(#input).val());
    }

    $(document).on("change", "#input", function(e) {
      runWhenReady();    
    });

    runWhenReady();  
});
```

I think that this will run `runWhenReady()` when `#input` is clicked, and when the page finishes loading. My question is, is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: define `webpage has finished loading` and we might be able to help.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify better what you mean when you say "finished loading". The `ready` event for instance is triggered when the DOM is ready. You want to wait for the images to load?

Comment: @Hodrobond I'm looking for something similar to `change` that I can add to the `.on()` method so that my 'function' will run after the page has loaded. This function (the one above) will already be wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @Romulo I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to do what I want is to name the function and call it two different ways.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function xyzzy(){
       $("#output").val($(#input).val());
    }

    //Call the function when #input is clicked
    $(document).on("change", "#input", function(e) {
      xyzzy();    
    });

    //Call the function when the page loads
    xyzzy();  
});
```

This will call the function when the page has finished loading, as well whenever `#input` is `clicked`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for `$(window).load()`

```
$(window).load(function(e){
    // code here
});
```

Answer to your question in the comments:

```
$(document).on('click', '#input', function(e){ 
    $('#output').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: I think this does almost the same thing as `$(document).ready(function(){});` which is not really what I was looking for..

Comment: How would I go about calling `$("#output").val($(#input).val());` when the page has finished loading, and whenever `#input` is clicked?

Comment: You should do $(document).on('click', '#input', function(e){   $('#output').val($(this).val())   })

Comment: I don't think that works. That will trigger when clicked, but it won't run unless it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I add a 'load' or something to this?

yes you can which will like `$(window).on( "load", handler )`

Also there is not much difference between the above code and

```
$( window).load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

The first method is just short cut of the second one

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready` happens when all the elements are present in the DOM, but not necessarily all content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("document is ready");
});
```

[window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

```
window.onload or $(window).load()
```

happens after all the content resources (images, etc) have been loaded.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    alert("window is loaded");
});
```

Comment: Okay, so how would I go about calling `$("#output").val($(#input).val());` when the page has finished loading, and whenever `#input` is clicked?

Comment: add inside $(document).ready(function(){$( '#input').click( function(){ $('#output').val($(this).val()) })} which reads all function with load than call whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

From your Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function runWhenReady(){
   $("#output").val($(#input).val());
}

$(document).on("change", "#input", function(e) {
  runWhenReady();    
});

runWhenReady();  
});
```

You could write:

```
$("#input").on("change", function() {...});
```

which defines a handler for your input. Everytime you change the value in the input it will call the function passed as argument. That make the whole $(document)... unneccessary.

If you want to run the function just once, as soon as possible wrap it in a IIFE like:

```
(function(){...});
```

Here is a pretty good blog post about IIFE:
http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/